# How can I know where the user touches?(AIR for android)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm trying to do that when the user touch (not click with mouse the program runs on android)
the code gets the (position of) touch x and y (like _xmouse but it dosen't work on android)
How can I do it?
Thank's!

Comment: just like MouseEvent , local and stage properties .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set up an **event listener function** for a TouchEvent, and in the event you get as a parameter you can use the following properties:

- **stageX**:  The horizontal coordinate at which the event occurred in global stage coordinates.
- **stageY**: The vertical coordinate at which the event occurred in global stage coordinates.
- **localX**: The horizontal coordinate at which the event occurred relative to the containing sprite.
- **localY**: The vertical coordinate at which the event occurred relative to the containing sprite.

for example:

```
mySprite.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);


function onTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent)
{
     trace("local coords (relatives to mySprite): " + e.localX+" "+e.localY);
     trace("global coords: " + e.stageX+" "+e.stageY);

}
```

For more info, take a look at the [Adobe reference for TouchEvent here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html).